# can't change default activate run first

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am still new on android area.
I just what to change the default activite to run first.
I what that my  TestprActivity.java will run first instead.
I know that it can be done by manifest file but I dont know how.
my manifist file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.News"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name="main.start" />
    <activity android:name=".NewsActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>


    </activity>

      <activity android:name=".WebActivity"/>

 </application>


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission> 
</manifest>
```

on run--->configuration I and find the wanted class to run first.
please give an example how it can be done.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The launcher activity of an application is defined by the respective intent filter

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Thus, you should add this filter to the activity you want. Note that only one activity should have this filter .